# RabbitMQ returning 404 closed by broker

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, pika

I have a RabbitMQ docker image i ran using the following commands:

```
docker pull rabbitmq

sudo  docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672  --name rabbitmq rabbitmq
```

Afterwards i try to run a python client with the `pika` module to get a connection to the rabbitmq server.

Before starting the server it gave a `ConnectionRefusedError` but after i have ran the image i get the following error:

`pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker: (404, "NOT_FOUND - no queue 'logs' in vhost '/'")`

Here is my python script that i use to establish a connection:

```py
from connection_manager import ConnectionManager
from mq_handler import MessageBroker

rabbit_mq_conn = ConnectionManager.init_connection()
mb = MessageBroker(rabbit_mq_conn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mb.run()
```

Comment: The code, as it is, fails with a message saying it doesn't know connection_manager. Are you sure you don't have to import Pika?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that works with pika and the Rabbit MQ docker container. It solves at least one issue that you seem to have, which is not creating a queue before using it.

```
import pika 

url = <rabbitMQ URL>
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
params.socket_timeout = 5

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params) # Connect to CloudAMQP
channel = connection.channel() # start a channel
channel.queue_declare(queue='my_channel') # Declare a queue
# send a message

channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='my_channel', body='My message')
connection.close()
```